# How can I access a method of a JLabel super class stored in a 2D array of JLabels

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a numbers game which involves creating a grid of JLabels which are stored in a 2D array.

The JLabels themselves are established by creating an object of the NumberPanel class which creates a JLabel displaying a random number.

In the main class which creates the objects via the 2D array I need to be able to access a method of the NumberPanel class called "isClicked" to set a boolean value to true or false.

I have pasted my code below, if anyone can give me a hand I would greatly appreciate it :)

```
**NumberPanel Class:**

public class NumberPanel extends JLabel {

    private boolean isClicked;

    NumberPanel() {
        //Constructor code
    }

    public void clicked(boolean b) {    //Need to access this method
        isClicked = b;
    }
}

**Original class containing NumberPanel objects**

public class NumberGameGui extends JPanel {

    private JLabel[][] numberGrid;

private void gridPopulator() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            numberGrid[i][j] = new NumberPanel();
            add (numberGrid[i][j]);
            numberGrid[i][j].addMouseListener (new PanelListener());
        }

    **NumberGrid[1][1].isClicked(true);** //Want to access isClicked method
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
((NumberPanel)numberGrid[1][1]).isClicked(true);
```

Or use NumberPanel as the static class of the array:

```
private NumberPanel[][] numberGrid;
```